# Is it possible to run an AngularJS application inside an MVC Partial View

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, view, partial

I'm trying run AnugularJS within an MVC application. It seems logical to me that this could be done by creating small angular application that would run when an MVC Partial View is pushed to the client.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />

<style>
    .gridStyle {
        border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
        width: 600px;
        height: 124px;
    }
</style>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="GridCtrl">
        <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div dropdownlist="" options="options" ng-model="selectedCategory" 
                        on-change="onChangeCategoryList()"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-show="contentAvailiable">
                        <div grid-angular=""></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/Libraries/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Libraries/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.13/build/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/directives.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/filters.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/services.js"></script>
```

```js
    angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.controllers', 'ngGrid'])


        .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'views/index',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
                })
                .state('grid', {
                    url: '/grid',
                    templateUrl: 'views/grid',
                    controller: 'GridCtrl'
                });

          //  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        }])


        .run(['$templateCache', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($templateCache, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

            var view = angular.element('#ui-view');
            $templateCache.put(view.data('tmpl-url'), view.html());

            // Allows to retrieve UI Router state information from inside templates
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {

                $rootScope.layout = toState.layout;
            });
        }]);
```

Instead of this working, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you load your Angular files before your `ng-app` directive.

Just put these files in your `</head>`:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Libraries/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Libraries/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.13/build/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/directives.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/filters.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/services.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

It is possible and very easy to use. Its just that you need to call the partial view using ng-include("'controller/action'"). Apostrophe(') is important while writing url.

Example

```
 <div id="TestDiv" ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
```

and inside the angular controller

```
 var app = angular.module("Layout", []);
    app.controller("LoadPage", function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

   //Initially
    $scope.templateUrl = '/Home/DefaultPage';

    // To dynamically change the URL.
    $scope.NewProjFn = function () {
        $scope.templateUrl = '/Home/ProjectPage';
    };
});
```

ng-include fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment. (Its all in one solution and for me best match for partial views)